Best practice when declaring imports with different execution contexts in python?
Say I have a Python project that looks like this:
project/
├── package/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module1.py
└── main.py

I would like package/ to be self-contained, though it is called from main.py.
Here are the contents of package/module1.py:
def some_fn():
    print("hi")

now say I want to call some_fn inside __init__.py. I have the following options:
1:
import module1


Benefit: can call when executing in package/
Drawback: fails to import when executing outside of package/

2:
import package.module1


Benefit: imports outside of package/
Drawback: fails to import when inside of package/

3:
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
import module1


Benefit: covers both cases
Drawback: ugly

Is there a preferred or idiomatic way of doing this?

Not a direct answer to your question, but are you aware that you can make the package executable by adding a __main__ module?

Do not go down the route of sys.path manipulation. That gets really difficult to debug. Instead, define a shared/global module namespace hierarchy. You can define multiple command line entrypoints, and can re-export objects under different names. You can also use relative imports like from . import module1 so that a module doesn't have to know its place in the module hierarchy, which makes it easier to move a package around. The drawback of scripts/entrypoints is that your project must be installed, ideally in a venv. Modern tools like poetry or uv make this a lot easier than pip.

@JimmyJames I am familiar with __main__.py and how it will enable you to python -m my_module, but does it help with relative imports?

@amon thanks for the response, an issue with relative imports like from . import module1 is I cannot use it independently, I would get the error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I'm not sure why you can't use relative imports inside the package and absolute imports from outside the package.  Are you trying to build a module that's both called from within a package and from a non-package context?

@JimmyJames that's basically it, I would like the modularity to be able to one day treat the submodule as its own standalone module without having to refactor the imports (if that makes sense). I can use relative imports inside & absolute outside so long as it is a submodule.

It seems you want to run commands like python3 package/script.py, which then does import module1? Or what does it mean to be "inside" the package? That approach is fundamentally misguided due to Python limitations. You should treat each module as always having a fixed global path under which it is installed (pip -e ., poetry install, uv sync). You can use sys.path hacks, but that sacrifices compatibility with lots of Python tooling. I recommend using a src-layout to provide a clear namespace root.

@amon yes that's correct. Here's an example: imagine I am writing a package to create print newspapers (called newspapers), and I have a subpackage that is meant to convert colours from RGB to CMYK called print_conversion. In the future, that subpackage might be useful as its own standalone package. Let's say in 5 years from now I want to make a new package to mass produce print photos. Well now I might want to use print_conversion again. I need to update the imports since it was originally a subpkg of newspapers. Totally aware this might be the wrong approach, hence why I'm asking!:)

That relative imports work differently depending on whether you are in a package context or not is one the 'features' of Python that annoys me and I have never really understood the need or reason for it (anyone who knows please comment.) It seems like a workaround for some sort of 'painting oneself into a corner' type of mistake.
In any event that's how it works in Python.  Here's a question on SO with a bunch of different answers and approaches so I don't see a need to reiterate what is already there.
My personal approach is to accept that once I have decided to go the package route, I commit to that and use the package-style imports for all use cases.  One situation where that becomes a challenge is if you have multiple modules that can be run as standalone scripts e.g., with a __name__ == "__main__": check and you want to make a package from those modules.  In that scenario, I've taken to changing the if statement to a method definition and then using the excellent typer library to create a CLI that calls those methods. The effort required to create a CLI with typer is so low that I don't even bother with other approaches.
